# How to upload a image with parameters android with post method

Tags: php, android

I am following this [link](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106) to upload a image. I am successfully sending image.

But how to send some parameters with same request.

These parameters i want to send

```
String urlFormation = WebConstants.UPLOAD_IMAGE;
Log.i(TAG, "urlFormation: ======"+urlFormation);
URL url = new URL(urlFormation);

// Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
conn.setRequestProperty("user_id", userID); 
conn.setRequestProperty("release_id", releaseID);
```

Please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the easy way is to use `GET`

```
yourscript.php?parm1=somevalue&param2=someothervalue
```

If you wanted `POST` you can append the data to the body of the request.